# Order of execution: variable declaration, assignment statement, expression

Tags: c

The following program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int twice(int a){
    return a * 2;
}

int main () {
    
    int b = twice(b);
    printf("%i\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

produces the output `0` without errors.

Why does it work without variable `b` being initialized? In Python, for example, a similar program would not work, and the Python interpreter will complain `b` being not defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: 1. It invokes *undefined behavior*. 2. Python isn't C.

Comment: *the Python interpreter will complain*. Most C compilers *will* complain if you turn up the warnings. For example, with `-Wall` in `gcc` will get: `warning: ‘b’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`

Comment: @kaylum, no, it does not.

Comment: Using an unintialised variable is Undefined Behaviour in C. That post describes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @WhozCraig
1. Please explain
2. I provided that example for comparison. You wouldn't expect me to think that C is Python, would you?

Comment: *Yes it does* exhibit a proper warning (which should always be treated as an error, but you still have to configure as much). [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/rqhdnK). 1. Evaluation of an indeterminate variable id in C invokes *undefined behavior*. That's how the language works. 2. No, I wouldn't, but you seem confused as to why the two  *different* languages appear to behave differently at compile-time, where one allows this and the other doesn't. They don't *necessarily* behave the same because, as different languages, they *are* necessarily *not* the same.

Comment: See [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re:

> produces the output `0` without errors

That *may* be true. It *may* also generate 42, or format your storage devices while playing `maniacal_laughter.mp3` on your sound device :-)

The problem lies with:

```c
int b = twice(b);
```

since it's functionally the same as:

```c
int b;
b = twice(b);
```

Note there the use of "functionally", it's not *strictly* the same since one is an initialisation and one is an assignment, but they're effectively identical for the purposes of this question.

The first line simply "creates" `b` and sets it to some arbitrary<sup>(a)</sup> value, the second line uses that value to change `b`.

This is not an *error* in C, it's simply undefined behaviour. However, a good compiler should pick this up and give you a warning, though it may need some options to do this such as with `gcc -Wall`:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:10:13: warning: ‘b’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   10 |     int b = twice(b);
      |             ^~~~~~~~
```

The reason this can happen in C but not Python is that the former *allows* you to create an uninitialised variable. In Python, a variable either doesn't exist at all (i.e., the name is not bound to a value) or it exists with some value.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> "Arbitrary", in this case, uses the mathematical definition of "undetermined, not assigned a specific value" rather than the definition making it a result of some specific whim by someone. The actual term used in the ISO standard is "indeterminate" for the language lawyers among us (of which I am usually one).

Keep in mind there's nothing requiring an implementation to have a *specific* value for an uninitialised variable. Though unlikely, it's perfectly plausible that the following code would generate two *different* numbers:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int x;
    printf("%d %d\n", x, x);
}
```

Comment: So the order in which `int b = twice(b)` executes would be (1) declaration, (2) expression to the right of assignment statement, (3) assignment statement. Right?

Comment: @satbekmyrza: yes, though technically the single-line variant is an initialisation rather than an assignment.

Comment: thanks! Have a great day! Could you also include that in your answer?

Comment: `b` has indeterminate value, not arbitrary value

Comment: @M.M: that's what arbitrary *means,* at least in the mathematical sense: undetermined, not assigned a specific value. But I'll clarify it to mention the term used in the standard.

Comment: @paxdiablo "arbitrary" implies to me that it has some valid value but we can't say what (i.e. simliar to the standard term "unspecified")

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you uss gcc, you should enable the [warning flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), especially these ones:

> -Werror
> Make all warnings into errors.

> -Wall
> This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid (or modify to prevent the warning), even in conjunction with macros.

> -Wextra
> This enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by -Wall.

And if you like [ISO C](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/ISO-C.html) (you should):

> -Wpedantic
> -pedantic
> Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other programs that do not follow ISO C and ISO C++

`gcc -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic test.c`

Now lets see if your program compile nicely... ;)